# En CSS, ¿cómo puedo transformar mi texto a tipo oración?

Tags: html, css

En CSS, ¿cómo puedo transformar mi texto a tipo oración? Es decir, la primera palabra después de un punto que sea mayúscula, no solo la inicial del párrafo.

Estoy usando `text-transform` para hacer que la primera palabra lleve mayúscula en títulos al menos, pero cuando quiero transformar el texto de un párrafo de lowercase a capitalize me pone todas las palabras en mayúscula: la primera letra y luego minúsculas. Lo que quiero es que de un texto así:

```
hola estoy aprendiendo css. tengo una duda con el texto. gracias.
```

se vea así:

```
Hola estoy aprendiendo css. Tengo una duda con el texto. Gracias.
```

Ya intenté con:

```css
p::first-letter {
text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

pero lo único que hace en el ejemplo anterior es:

```
Hola estoy aprendiendo css. tengo una duda con el texto. gracias.
```

Solo a *Hola* le pone mayúscula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes encerrar cada frase en una etiqueta `span`, y aplicar el estilo css a `p span::first-letter`

Es un poco tedioso, y no le veo mucho sentido (tardas menos en escribir tú la letra en mayúscula), pero podría servirte.

Si no, ya habría que tirar de javascript y ver qué se podría hacer